# How to resolve ambiguous method reference in scala

Tags: scala, slf4j

Here is the specific issue I am encountering. I am using [SLF4J Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) (The type of the variable `logger` below)

```
//After adding to a map
logger debug ("Adding {} = {}", key, value)
```

Here is what mouse  hover in eclipse  (and the compiler) tell me.

> ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method debug in trait Logger of type (x$1: String, x$2: Object*)Unit and method debug in trait Logger of type (x$1: String, x$2: Any, x$3: Any)Unit match argument types (String,String,String)

**I understand why they are ambiguous. I am certainly not arguing with the compiler :). I want to simply know how seasoned programmers solve this issue.**

Here are the alternatives I can use

1. Create and array , and ride the `Object*` definition

   `logger debug ("Adding {} = {}", Array(key, value):_*)`
2. Cast to `Any`

   `logger debug ("Adding {} = {}", key.asInstanceOf[Any], value.asInstanceOf[Any])`

Neither approach is particularly appealing. Does the community have a better approach or suggestions for me?

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like it might be a known issue - see [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/scalalogging/issues/16)

Comment: I think that's it. Thanks for your help @Shadowlands! If you could post that as an answer, I can mark the question solved and we can help the community.

Comment: With string interpolation, i just always use `logger debug (s"Adding $key = $value)` these data. Since string interpolation is compile time, it's probably more efficient as well

Comment: @ArneClaassen sorry for my ignorance. But what is the "s" in your code?

Comment: Scala 2.10 added string interpolation. "s" and others like it are explained here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: Wow! I learn something new and valuable just by admitting my ignorance :) Thanks @ArneClaassen!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off a nod of credit to @Shadowlands, @ArneClaassen and  @OlgeRudenko. 
As mentioned in the comments, this does seem to be known issue. That stopped me from trying to "solve" it. The next thing to do was to find a good work around that did not break Scala idioms.

With these constraints in mind I chose to go with **String Interpolation** as suggested above. I also switched to [scala-logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging). Quoting from their GitHub/README,

> Scala Logging is a convenient and performant logging library wrapping SLF4J. It's convenient, because you can simply call log methods without checking whether the respective log level is enabled:
>
> logger.debug(s"Some $expensive message!")
>
> It's performant, because thanks to Scala macros the check-enabled-idiom is applied, just like writing this more involved code:
>
> if (logger.isDebugEnabled) logger.debug(s"Some $expensive message!")

Thanks all! As far as I am concerned, this is resolved. If the commentators can post their answers, I will be happy to acknowledge them.

As always, feels good to be standing on the shoulders of friendly giants!

**PS:** I just verified that there is no execution cost to String interpolation **if you are using scala-logging**. My verification method was crude but effective.

```
    log.debug{ 
        {
          throw new IllegalAccessException("This should not have been called with debug off!")
        }
        s"Added Header ${name}:${headerValue}"
      }
```

Sure enough, when I set my log to `DEBUG`, the exception is thrown, *as expected* , but vanishes when I set it to a level higher.
And yes, I have already removed the `IllegalAccessException` part :).

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention. I have switched to scala-logging. There is no cost of execution for debug statements unless debug is true.

Answer (score 15):

I would use

```
logger.debug("Adding {} = {}", key, value: Any)
```

Alternatively following can be used:

```
logger.debug("Adding {} = {}", Array(key, value):_*)
```

Please pay attention to `:_*`. Should you omit these symbols and it will call `Object*` method providing only 1 argument, which will be an array.

Comment: Yes, @OlegRudenko you are correct in pointing out the mistake. I did not type that properly. I am guessing when  I wrote Object*, I must have mentally checked off _* . Anyway a mistake is a mistake. Thanks for correcting it. I will correct my original question.

Comment: Seems that the first approach is preferable over the second which creates an array even if the log level is disabled. Perhaps wrap that version in a check that debug is enabled?

Comment: Use scala-logging. :) The answers just to show how to resolve ambiguous method references. Concerning performance: my experience shows that you should concentrate on readability of the code and optimize performance ONLY if you really see the need.